# Subtract values in each row of a column based on a WHERE and GROUP BY statement in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to subtract each row "Value" with the "Value" where Sub1=0 grouping by ID_1 and ID_2 using a SQL query.

This is the table structure:

```
------------------------------------
ID_1 |ID_2 | sub1 | Value
------------------------------------
1    | a   | 0    | 20  
1    | a   | 50   | 30   
1    | a   | 100  | 40   
1    | b   | 0    | 25   
1    | b   | 50   | 30   
1    | b   | 100  | 50   
2    | a   | 0    | 5  
2    | a   | 50   | 10   
2    | a   | 100  | 30   
2    | b   | 0    | 25   
2    | b   | 50   | 50   
2    | b   | 100  | 70
```

I would like to group by ID_1 and ID_2 and subtract each row's value with the value where the Sub1=0

Output table should be :

```
------------------------------------
ID_1 |ID_2 | sub1 | Value | Diff
------------------------------------
1    | a   | 0    | 20    | 0
1    | a   | 50   | 30    | 10
1    | a   | 100  | 40    | 20
1    | b   | 0    | 25    | 0
1    | b   | 50   | 30    | 5
1    | b   | 100  | 50    | 25
2    | a   | 0    | 5     | 0
2    | a   | 50   | 10    | 5
2    | a   | 100  | 30    | 25
2    | b   | 0    | 25    | 0
2    | b   | 50   | 50    | 25
2    | b   | 100  | 70    | 45
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
select t1.*, t1.value - t2.value as diff
from t t1
left join t t2 on t2.id_1 = t1.id_1 and t2.id_2 = t1.id_2 and t2.sub1 = 0
```

See it here:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cab4d5/1

Answer (score 0):

Use a window function:

```
select t.*,
       (value - 
        sum(case when sub1 = 0 then value else 0 end) over (partition by id_1, id_2)
       ) as diff
from t;
```